# Get all WiFi-Direct devices nearby

Tags: android, wifi-direct

How to get the names of all WiFi-Direct devices nearby for a period of time, lets say 3 hours, while sending the own name constantly.
All is managed an by an app, the goal here is to get all names of Wifi-Direct devices you came across.
Is this draining a lot of battery?
Thx ueen

Comment: https://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2012/08/31/android-wifi-direct-example/ Look at this example u ll get ur answer

Comment: http://www.drjukka.com/blog/wordpress/ This blog has a lot of posts about Wi-Fi Direct performance and battery usage. Also some more Wi-Fi Direct resources: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wi-fi-direct/uWpuOzHY6y0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose my old test app would do exactly that, so check out the [WifiTestPower](https://github.com/DrJukka/WifiTestPower)

Also do check old post (2015 summer I suppose) from [my blog](http://www.drjukka.com/blog/wordpress/), there are articles on issues devices going blind on Wifi Direct services, as well as power consumption talks as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this-

```
public class WiFiDemo extends Activity implements OnClickListener
 {      
    WifiManager wifi;       
    ListView lv;
    TextView textStatus;
    Button buttonScan;
    int size = 0;
    List<ScanResult> results;

    String ITEM_KEY = "key";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    SimpleAdapter adapter;

    /* Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
        buttonScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonScan);
        buttonScan.setOnClickListener(this);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (wifi.isWifiEnabled() == false)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wifi is disabled..making it enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }   
        this.adapter = new SimpleAdapter(WiFiDemo.this, arraylist, R.layout.row, new String[] { ITEM_KEY }, new int[] { R.id.list_value });
        lv.setAdapter(this.adapter);

        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) 
            {
               results = wifi.getScanResults();
               size = results.size();
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));                    
    }

    public void onClick(View view) 
    {
        arraylist.clear();          
        wifi.startScan();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning...." + size, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try 
        {
            size = size - 1;
            while (size >= 0) 
            {   
                HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();                       
                item.put(ITEM_KEY, results.get(size).SSID + "  " + results.get(size).capabilities);

                arraylist.add(item);
                size--;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                 
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { }         
    }    
}
```

Comment: Op asked WIFI direct not this. Above answer is not solve the question :)

Comment: oh my bad @ueen you can use this link for solution - http://stackoverflow.com/q/17530885/842607